# $.ajax success function is not working for me.

Tags: php, jquery

Friends i have a problem.I have a member area function which will display the count of inbox messages using jquery.

This is what i did.

```
function listner_requests(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://src.abc.com/listner.php",
  data: "action=listner_requests",
  success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr) { alert(responseText);                               
  },
 error: function(data, statusCode) {
    alert("ERROR: "+data)
    }
  });
    }
```

**listner.php**

```
if($_POST['action']=="listner_requests"){
$sql="SELECT messages FROM friend_requests WHERE message_to='".$_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']."'";
$data=mysql_query($sql,$profile);
$count=mysql_num_rows($data);
echo $count;
exit();
}
```

i excecute the php without ajax to test if it is working or not. it is perfectly working.

but if i use ajax method it won't alert the correct response.
it generates an error. have i done a wrong thing? please help me. thanks

Comment: check your browser console for any errors.

Comment: ERROR: [object Object] this what i got in alert

Comment: The `data` in your `error` is XHR format. use `data.statusText` or `data.responseText` and tell us what that says.

Comment: data.statusText returns error and nothing displays for data.responseText

Comment: Maybe try to use a relative path? like `../file.php`. Maybe the browser thinks it's cross-domain.

Comment: @Rune tried but no luck same error popups

Comment: @Rune i think you are correct.I got the answer it just because of my sub-domain.I am using the outputs in a different sub-domain.if i use both files in the same sub-domain it works. Thanks all of you my friends.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution - but a comment to help debug (can't post in comment as the code wont appear)

Your code:

```
  success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr) {
      alert(responseText);                                
  }, 
  error: function(data, statusCode) { 
      alert("ERROR: "+data) 
  }
```

is a bit misleading as you have the paramters muddled up. You'll find it clearer to debug with:

```
  success: function(data) {
      alert(data);                                
  }, 
  error: function(xhr, status, textError) { 
    alert('Error ' + xhr.responseText + ' - ' + status + ' - ' + textError); 
  }
```

If xhr.responseText is blank (as you said in comments), then textError will probably reveal the answer. Failing that, status will...

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Robbie its just displays "Error -error-" that means status is error, other two are blank

Answer (score 0):

assuming u want count as response .. i would prefer returned data as json ...
check this out... see if it works...

```
function listner_requests(){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType:'json',
url: "http://src.abc.com/listner.php",
data: "action=listner_requests",
success: function(data) { alert(data.totalcount);                               
},
error: function(data, statusCode) {
alert("ERROR: "+data)
}
});
}
```

listener.php

```
if($_POST['action']=="listner_requests"){
$sql="SELECT messages FROM friend_requests WHERE         message_to='".$_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']."'";
$data=mysql_query($sql,$profile);
$count=mysql_num_rows($data);
echo json_encode(array('totalcount'=>$count));
exit();
```

}